# How to change the language of a wordpress.com blog?

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting, multi-language

I'm using my wordpress.com blog (not wordpress.org) and want to change the language of the blog. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it here http://en.support.wordpress.com/language-settings/

Comment: Is it just me, or is this not possible / available anymore in both 3.4(.1-.3) and 3.5(beta 1)?